# How do you disable the title in Twitter Bootstrap's popover plugin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using popover to display an image which doesn't require a title.  If you don't set "title", it still displays an area where the title would be.  How do you turn this off completely?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

baptme's suggest is ok, but the better way would be to specify your popover's title and actually hide it completely as margins still exist with a height of 0.

```
.popover-title { display: none; }
```

Edit:  just quicky looked at the source and there seems to be an undocumented option:

```
$.fn.popover.defaults = $.extend({} , $.fn.tooltip.defaults, {
    placement: 'right'
  , content: ''
  , template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
  })
```

When you declare your popover using JS, try to override the template and specify a hidden title.

```
$('#example').popover({
    template: '...<h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none"></h3>...'
});
```

<strike>The reason I say don't remove it is it may cause runtime errors if the element doesn't exist.</strike>  See Sherbrow's comment.

Comment: If the popover is $('#example').popover(options), then what's the CSS to go to this element id and not all popover titles?

Comment: The popover element is created on mouseover and destroyed on mouseleave.  You can't specifically target that element.  See my edit for a possible solution

Comment: @Terry you can remove it, since it's used with a jQuery selector : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3GMnz/

Comment: @Terry major +1 for making us aware of the undocumented `template: ` option

Answer (score 11):

In Bootstrap 2.3+ the title automatically hides if empty.

http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/02/07/bootstrap-2-3-released/

Answer (score 5):

I wound up using a combination of the techniques suggested by @Terry and @Sherbow.   Shows the image, but not the title (for this popup only).

```
<a href="#" id="contributors" rel="popover">contributors</a>

...

<script>
var contributor_img = '<img src="my_img/contributor.png" />'


$(function ()
{ $('#contributors').popover({ 
    content: contributor_img, 
    template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>' });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the easy way is to do set `height:0px` on the class `.popover-title` and don't use `data-original-title`

**CSS:**

```
.popover-title { height: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a function to remove the element:

```
function removeTitle(){
  $('.popover-title').remove();
}

$("a[data-toggle=popover]")
  .popover({
     html: true,
     animation: true
})
.click(function(e) {
  removeTitle();
  e.preventDefault()
})
```