# Bootstrap popover without title

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popovers.There are many popovers on the page and in one of the popover , I dont want to display the title,when I dont give Title, it still shows that area where the title would have been.
Found an answer on [How do you disable the title in Twitter Bootstrap's popover plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224892/how-do-you-disable-the-title-in-twitter-bootstraps-popover-plugin)

but cant give css : display:none
to popover-title class since that would hide title from all other  popovers also.

What should be the correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your exact code or similar example .. Cannot possible guess what is wrong without it :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I think it's pretty clear without code. Adding the css rule to the `popover-title` class would affect all pop-overs on the page, but he only wants to remove the title from one popover.

Comment: @Paulpro, yes - but if I'm not defining `data-title` on a popover-element, _the title is not shown_! (not even an empty title, as expected) So there must be something else going on with his code

Comment: @davidkonrad , but when i dont define title, it still shows the space.. prob got solved nw by overriding the template:          


 placement: 'right'
  , content: ''
  , template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

Comment: Hey @user2688204 - great! you should consider answering your own question below (where you describe your solution) and mark it as accepted. This would be perfect. Others could may benefit from your effort and perhaps upvote your answer when they search for answers ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks.. got it worked by overriding the template

```
showpopover=function(message,context){
    var popover_message="<div>"+message+"</div>";
    //$(a).hide();
    $popover=$(context).popover({ placement:"bottom",trigger:"hover",template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',content:popover_message}).popover('show'); 
};
```

how i called the function is here:

```
html = html + "<td onmouseover=\"showpopover('"+main_image_data['score_reason']+"',this)\"><center>"+main_image_data['bonus']+"</center></td>";
```

It works :)

Comment: Which file did you change?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the template for a popover using the admittedly undocumented template option. This is described in one of the answers to the question you posted (not the accepted one). I'd use this method if it's only for some popovers on the page.

Edit: this has some drawbacks of course: updating bootstrap means making sure your template still fits, which is exactly the reason this option is not documented (I imagine).

Comment: Good answer! But should really not be nessecary since title / no title already is taken care of in bootstrap, based on the `data-title` attribute.

Comment: Actually that's true, I agree, and this is already mentioned in the answers to the question the OP linked to, so I assume he's either using an older bootstrap version or something in his code is messing with things... no idea. However there are many ways to use bootstrap, for example integrating it with knockout like I'm doing now, and things can get non-obvious there. I had to mess with the template as well to get everything the way I wanted.

Comment: Yes, agree. Thats exactly why I was angling for some code / example, to better figure out what was wrong :) In general I feel there is some tag-confusion regarding "bootstrap", where bootstrap / twitter bootstrap / bootstrap v3 often is tagged similar.